# Match cell values across two sheets in same worksheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have two sheets in one google doc.

They both contain product codes, one has 3427 product codes, and the other has 1205 product codes. The sheet with the 1205 codes is the newer one, and I'd like to compare the two sheets for matches. They are both in column A.

So, in sheet one, I want to highlight all matches with sheet two.

The reason for this is that sheet a has ALL product codes stored on our internal systems, even expired products. List two has only our current products. I want to highlight our current range in sheet one, so I can quickly delete the old items.

The full sheet which i have not linked has a lot of data that does not match across the two.

Here is what it looks like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f_4t7m2NmEFu2YbT_-VAwn_o9WHk45Sr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is what I have tried so far, but it seems to be highlightin ALL cells in that column:

=A2:A3427<>INDIRECT("from woo!A:A")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following formula in CF:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'from woo'!A:A"),A2)
```

It will mark all entries found on the page '`from woo`'

[image]